# How to transform this portion of webconfig in my web.config.release?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, xslt

I need to change SMTP host value on web.config transform. Here is what I have:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="some@sioem.com">
        <network host="localhost" userName="" password=""/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

How should I put it in web.release.config so instead of localhost it says 192.168.1.9 ?

I transform connection string like this but not sure how to do it with smtp

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="CoreModelContext"
    connectionString="metadata=&&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Might take a look here: http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2010/02/17/ASPNET-40-Part-4-Config-Transformation-Files.aspx

Comment: The link is not opening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp>
      <network xdt:Transform="Replace" host="192.168.1.9" userName="" password="" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```